# "Bigger" or "longer" hours overlap?

Tags: word-usage

What is more correct saying about hours?

1. A **bigger** overlap of our business hours.
2. A **longer** overlap of our business hours.

**UPDATE**

The context: we want to shift working hours, so employees from different countries work together longer.

Comment: [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+bigger+overlap+of%2Ca+longer+overlap+of%2Ca+greater+overlap+of+&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20greater%20overlap%20of%3B%2Cc0) correspond to my feelings about the idiomatic choice here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help to better understand what you are trying to convey here, as my feeling from everyday usage of the English language is that neither fit perfectly. A suggestion instead would be:

> An increased overlap of our business hours

Comment: I've added an update